# iOS: GPS location updates only work for 10 seconds when starting monitoring from background (beacon)

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, core-location, ibeacon

We're trying to create an app which records a GPS log of a journey when the phone is in the presence of a beacon/iBeacon. For example, if you put the beacon in your car, then all your car journeys would be recorded automatically.

However we've immediately run into a problem. If we record the journey with the app in the foreground, everything works fine. However if we start recording the journey from the DidRangeBeacons() callback, we seem to only get 10 seconds of data and then the app gets suspended.   We have put the required properties in the Info.plist file:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>location</string>
</array>
```

Additionally, the app is correctly registered to allow location monitoring when running in the background (and calls locMgr.RequestAlwaysAuthorization() if necessary) and all looks OK on the Location Privacy screen in iOS.

Something seems to be stopping the OS to recognise that the app has permission to track location in the background. Or possibly we're starting the location monitoring in the wrong way by directly calling CLLocationManager.StartUpdatingLocation() from the DidRangeBeacons() callback.

What can we do to get around this 10 second limit we appear to be hitting?

We are using Xamarin in this instance, but I'm sure we'd have the same issue if we were in Objective C as I suspect this is a design problem with misuse of the APIs, so any help or code samples from either platform would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Just because `UIBackgroundModes` `location` is set, doesn't mean iOS has no restrictions on the app running in the background.  Read [Using Location Services in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html) for details.

Beacon region entry events generally limit you to 10 seconds of background ranging (and other background operations).  You can extend this 10 seconds to 180 seconds through the technique described [here.](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/11/13/extending-background-ranging-on-ios.html)  With background modes, you should be able to extend indefinitely.

Comment: OK, so during the beacon ranging event, it should be enough to start a new background thread for recording GPS location?

Comment: Yes, but you won't necessarily be able to keep that background thread going forever.  I know you can keep it going for 180 seconds.

Comment: But how do you keep it going indefinitely? There are hundreds of apps in the app store which record walks/runs/rides for unlimited time.

Comment: I have modified my answer.  As @goldmine pointed out in his answer, the location background mode should allow you to extend beyond the 180 seconds in the blog post I mentioned indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that the app continues to receive location updates you should start a [background task](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3). This will make sure that your app does not get suspended. Normally background tasks are allowed 3 minutes of execution but if you specify for the location background permission in the plist (which you did), you will have unlimited time. There is still the possibility that the app might get terminated by the OS if it needs to free up memory for another foreground app. However, you can also [monitor for significant location change](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges). This will trigger about every 500m-1km (as cellular towers and available wifi networks around changes) and will actually relaunch the app if it was terminated (as the beacon monitoring service). Does this make sense?